# Write Response code and Error text from gatling to graphite influxDB

Tags: performance-testing, grafana, influxdb, gatling

I have connected the gatling to influxDB with all the configuration mentioned in its website. I can see pass fail, ResponseTime, StDev, requestname in influxDB. Now I need to add Response code for KO transactions and its error message. Can anyone let me know, if that can be added and how

The configuration doe so far

gatling.conf :

1. writers = [console, file, graphite]
2. graphite {
   light = false              # only send the all* stats
   host = "localhost"         # The host where the Carbon server is located
   port = 2003                # The port to which the Carbon server listens to (2003 is default for plaintext, 2004 is default for pickle)
   protocol = "tcp"           # The protocol used to send data to Carbon (currently supported : "tcp", "udp")
   rootPathPrefix = "gatling" # The common prefix of all metrics sent to Graphite
   bufferSize = 8192          # GraphiteDataWriter's internal data buffer size, in bytes
   writeInterval = 1          # GraphiteDataWriter's write interval, in seconds
   }

InfluxDB.conf

```
 templates = [
            "gatling.*.*.*.* measurement.simulation.request.status.field",
            "gatling.*.users.*.* measurement.simulation.measurement.request.field"
    ]
```

Appriciate your help and thank you

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible with Gatling OSS.

Please note those metrics are available in [FrontLine](https://gatling.io/gatling-frontline/) though.

[image: statuses]

[image: errors]

Comment: Hi Stephane
Thank you for the update, but if it can be achieved by frontline and as all the data is already available in simulation.log, is it not possible to get it using influxDB-grafana integration

Comment: No it's not, as I stated.